Why does combining measures produce different results in Power BI / DAX
I have developed a measure in parts using two separate measures. As a final step, i combined them together using a variable for the helper measure, only to discover that the results are different.
While I can leave these separate, hide the helper measure, and move on, I'm attempting to better understand why this is happening.
Helper measure
CountRowMeasureInsta = COUNTROWS(
    FILTER('Instagram_Combined', 'Instagram_Combined'[BestPerformedContent] <> BLANK()
    )
)

RankX (working - RankX uses helper measure)
RankXInsta = 
VAR CRMI = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Instagram_Combined,Instagram_Combined[BestPerformedContent] <> BLANK()))
 
VAR RX = IF ( NOT ( ISBLANK ( CRMI)),
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALL('Instagram_Combined'[BestPerformedContent]),
        'Instagram_Combined'[BestPerformedContent] <> BLANK()
    ),[CountRowMeasureInsta],,,Dense)
)
RETURN RX

RankX (not working - everything ranked as 1, no helper measure)
RankXInsta = 
VAR CRMI = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Instagram_Combined,Instagram_Combined[BestPerformedContent] <> BLANK()))
 
VAR RX = IF ( NOT ( ISBLANK ( CRMI)),
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALL('Instagram_Combined'[BestPerformedContent]),
        'Instagram_Combined'[BestPerformedContent] <> BLANK()
    ),CRMI,,,Dense)
)
RETURN RX

sample data
|BestPerformedContent|
|ACMS Ticket Lauch Real|
|Agata Stafiej-Bartosik (Country Rep) was elected to the Council of The National Freedom Institute � Centre for Civil Society Developmen|
|announcement of new members of the board of Ashoka in Poland|
|announcement of streaming about Ashoka Changemakers challenge|
...
Working

Not Working

Insights into what I am missing are greatly appreciated.

found the answer on sqlbi here "a variable is a name assigned to a value. The value is computed and assigned to the variable once and for all. In other words, variables are – surprisingly enough – constants."
